# Use drm_scheme clearkey in android

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am encrypting video using clearkey. And want play with exoplayer in Android studio. Am able to play video without encryption. But not getting how to play using clearkey. It's giving me DrmSession error. If anybody knows please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if (C.CLEARKEY_UUID != null) {
                intent.putExtra(Player.DRM_SCHEME_UUID_EXTRA, C.CLEARKEY_UUID.toString());
                intent.putExtra(Player.DRM_LICENSE_URL, "url/clearkey.json");
                intent.putExtra(Player.DRM_KEY_REQUEST_PROPERTIES, drmKeyRequestProperties);
            }
```